# How can I print a map object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string and then increases all characters by 2.
The problem is that when I try to print the result the output is non-existant.

This is the code:

```
def plustwo(text):
    text = list(text)
    numbers = map(ord, text)
    for a in numbers:
        a += 2
    letters = map(chr, numbers)
    return letters

data = open("dati.txt")
readed = data.read()
sentence = plustwo(readed)

for letter in sentence:
    print(sentence)
```

And there is no output.

Comment: `a += 2` just creates a new local variable `a` with your augmented values, but never updates the list item. You want `for idx, a in enumerate(numbers): numbers[idx] = a + 2` to do that, or probably more simply create a new list with a list comprehension: `numbers = [number+2 for number in numbers]`.

Comment: (I would think that we have a duplicate for such a classic problem, but couldn't find any... Does anyone know one?)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille They're using Python 3.

Comment: @KellyBundy ? what's the relevance?

Comment: You can use the built-in `translate` method. `sentence = readed.translate(dict((x, x+2) for x in range(1000)))`. (Pick whatever range of Unicode ordinals you actually need to worry about.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thierry said "list item". But in Python 3, `map` no longer returns a list. And you can't assign into it like Thierry suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thierry has mentioned his first comment, you are just incrementing a local variable inside the function: `a` is NOT a reference to individual characters in a list, but a new variable. (In fact, `map` in Python 3 is an iterator, not a list.) Try this instead:

```
def shift_n(text, shift=2):
    current_numbers = map(ord, text)
    new_numbers = [number+shift for number in current_numbers]
    new_letters = map(chr, new_numbers)
    return ''.join(new_letters)
```

or a bit condensed:

```
def shift_n(text, shift=2):
    numbers = (number+shift for number in map(ord, text))
    return ''.join(map(chr, numbers))
```

Comment: Or even `return ''.join([chr(ord(c)+shift) for c in text])`